# Why does Model return a Null exception when using it in my Index.cshtml file? No information is displayed on launch

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Community, ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller) with the most recent version of .NET.

I'm having an issue where the data I'm extracting from the database I've connected to won't display on the webpage when I run the program. I also get a Null exception when I don't add the "?? Enumerable.Empty()" condition to the foreach loop I tried to create using Model. I will include the Model, Data, Controllers, index.cshtml file.

Model file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace Northwind_API.Models
{
    public class ProductInfo
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid product_id { get; set; }
        public string product_name { get; set; }
        public int supplier_id { get; set; }

        public int category_id { get; set; }
        public string quantity_per_unit { get; set; }

        public double unit_price { get; set; }

        public int units_in_stock { get; set; }

        public int units_on_order { get; set; }

        public int reorder_level { get; set; }

        public int discontinued { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Data file:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Northwind_API.Models;

namespace Northwind_API.Data
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    { 
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<ProductInfo> Info { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Northwind_API.Data;
using Northwind_API.Models;

namespace Northwind_API.Controllers
{

    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        public readonly ILogger<ValuesController> _logger;
        public readonly DataContext _context;


        public ValuesController(ILogger<ValuesController> logger, DataContext context)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context;
        }


        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_context.Info.ToList());
        }

        
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml file:

```
@using Northwind_API.Models;
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="row"><p><h2>Category Name</h2></p></div>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="table- responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped custom table mb-0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product ID</th>

                        <th>Product Name</th>
                        <th>Supplier ID</th>
                        <th>Category ID</th>
                        <th>Unit Price</th>
                        <th>Units in stock</th>
                        <th>Units on order</th>
                        <th>Reorder level</th>
                        <th>Discontinued</th>

                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    @foreach (var item in Model ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>())
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@item.product_id</td>
                            <td>@item.product_name</td>
                            <td>@item.supplier_id</td>
                            <td>@item.category_id</td>
                            <td>@item.unit_price</td>
                            <td>@item.units_in_stock</td>
                            <td>@item.units_on_order</td>
                            <td>@item.reorder_level</td>
                            <td>@item.discontinued</td>
                        </tr>

                    }

                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: I added a picture of the map of tables in the database provided to me.
[image: Picture of database tables]

Comment: Hi @to_Bewilder, what's the version of your asp.net core? Actually I have tested your code and if it does not have any data in database, it also work without any exception no matter you use the ?? or not.

Comment: .NET Core 3.1 LTS. There should be data in the database because I needed to use a connection string to connect to the database. This is all part of a project assigned to me so I should be able to use the information I specified in my variables.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a model to index view

```
@model List<ProductInfo>
....

@if (@Model!=null && @Model.Count > 0)
{
     @foreach (var item in Model)
     {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@item.product_id</td>
                            <td>@item.product_name</td>
                            <td>@item.supplier_id</td>
                            <td>@item.category_id</td>
                            <td>@item.unit_price</td>
                            <td>@item.units_in_stock</td>
                            <td>@item.units_on_order</td>
                            <td>@item.reorder_level</td>
                            <td>@item.discontinued</td>
                        </tr>
     }
}
```

UPDATE

You just posted you db  and I see that you need to map your class to table

```
[Table("Products")] 
public class ProductInfo
```

Comment: Sorry, still nothing.

Comment: @to_Bewilder sorry, what means nothing?

Comment: I changed to code to your recommendation and the page that I created still doesn't display the info I need it too.

Comment: @to_Bewilder Why it should display if you don't have any data in your db or your db is not confugured properly?